# Can Log4j2 be configured with .xml and .properties at the same time?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

As above, can log4j2 be configured at the same time with .xml and .properties?
And if it can, what takes priority, when changing shared configuration?

Answer (score 1):

### **This is the direct answer**

Firstly: Why would you want to have multiple configuration files? Seems to me like you should try to collate all of your configuration into one file if at all possible.

The [documentation for Log4J2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) says that the automatic configuration will search first for the System property "log4j.configurationFile", which points to one configuration file on the file system, which is loaded based on the type of file.

If that isn’t found, it will search for:

1. .properties
2. .yml
3. .json
4. .xml

In that order.

This to me means that you can only use one.

### **This provides another approach**

You can, however programmatically configure the logger, which can combine a configuration file with a different set of configurations.

If you wanted to combine the **Configurator method** with XML configuration, for example, then [apparently you have to use the ConfigurationFactory](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html), which is something I have never done before, though if you understand the layout of the Log4J2 it doesn't look too difficult - basically extending `ConfigurationFactory`, overriding methods to configure things, then giving the `Configurator` the factory.

Additional links:

[Here is the programmatic configuration documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html)

[Here is a helpful Baeldung articl for programmatic configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-programmatic-config)